# Read string from clipboard

Tags: ios, swift

How can I read a string from the clipboard and write it on a button's title?  I can copy a string to the clipboard with:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Hello world"
```

But how do I read that string from the clipboard and assign it to a String?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just read it back into a variable like this:

```
let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
if let theString = pasteboardString {
    print("String is \(theString)")
}
```