# Get currently highlighted text in OSX app?

Tags: macos, swift

Is there a way to detect the currently selected/ highlighted text from an OSX app and store it in a string?

For example, if I go onto Safari and highlight a paragraph from a random website, then launch my app, is there a way to get the text I highlighted in Safari?

I haven't heard of this, but I'm not an example so I wasn't sure if it was possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: If the user copies it to the clipboard, you could get it from there (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376863/read-string-from-clipboard)).  I doubt if you can get something that was simply highlighted, but not copied, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: You would need to get a list of every window, and check them for `NSText` instances, then get the highlighted text from there.

Comment: I am able to get a list of all the open windows, but how am I able to check for NSText instances? Could you maybe link me to some documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general to get the selected text from another app you need your process to be accessibility enabled. That is it needs to be authorized to control the system. 
In code you could then use the AX Accessibility API or you could use AppleScript with "System Events"

With Safari you could have a custome extension, but that would be just as complex and less ROI.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any application that uses Command C to copy, i.e.  virtually all.  Example below is with Safari. Before running make sure the user has highlighted text in Safari and does not subsequently change tabs or windows. Its OK if the user focuses on another app though. The delays are critical.  You can probably get away with less time, but it all depends on the state of the users system at the time of running, so the longer the delay the more robust the process.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Safari" to activate -- focus on Safari's current tab
    delay 0.25 --critical
    keystroke "c" using command down -- copy clipboard contents
    delay 0.25 --critical
end tell

set highlightedText to the clipboard as Unicode text
display dialog highlightedText -- just to see the results, otherwise delete

set the clipboard to "" -- return clipboard to blank state
```

If you are just going to do this with Safari then the following is your best bet and delays usually not needed.  Otherwise, same provisos as above.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set highlightedText to (do JavaScript "(''+getSelection())" in document 1) as string
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the current selected text (box) from any application, while the user is typing